# Generate percentile from histogram type data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with histogram type data. There are 2 columns: Bucket, Count.

Bucket is the histogram bucket and Count is the number of values in that bucket.

Now my buckets are ordered so for example, let's say that the bucket indicates minutes it took to complete a task. We could have buckets such as 0-5 minutes, 5-10 minutes, 10-15, etc.

What I'm trying to compute is which bucket falls in the XXth percentile. For example, if 90% of tasks complete in 12 minutes, then I want to know that 90% of tasks are in the 10-15 bucket or less.

As an example, say I have the following table:

```
Bucket | Count
--------------
  0    | 10
  1    | 15
  2    | 5
  3    | 15
```

If I want to compute the 60th percentile. It'd be

(10+15+5+15)*.60 = 27 so the result would be bucket 2 since 60% of all entries are in bucket 2 or less

Is there a way to compute this in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "histogram" data type?

Comment: The data in my table is formatted in such a way as to optimize hisogram views. So just like I said above, I have a column for the bucket, then Count for the number of "tasks" that fall into that bucket.

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` and sample insert statements, so that those of us not fluent in histograms can piece together what you're talking about?

Comment: Which SQL Server version ? `SELECT @@VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

Note: `COUNT` is a reserved SQL word so maybe you should use valueCount.

Should be something like that (assuming your table is called histogramTable):

```
SELECT bucket, 
    (SELECT SUM(valuecount) 
        FROM histogramTable AS in1 
        WHERE in1.bucket <= ot.bucket
    ) * 100 / (
            SELECT SUM(valueCOUNT) 
            FROM histogramTable AS in1
            ) As Percentile
FROM histogramTable AS ot
```

Of course, I didn't convert any value in `DECIMAL` data type, so you'll be losing some precision with your `Percentile` column.

Then let's say you need the bucket representing Percentile 80:

```
DECLARE @Percentile AS INT
SET @Percentile = 80

SELECT TOP 1 bucket FROM(
SELECT bucket, 
    (SELECT SUM(valuecount) 
        FROM histogramTable AS in1 
        WHERE in1.bucket <= ot.bucket
    ) * 100 / (
            SELECT SUM(valueCOUNT) 
            FROM histogramTable AS in1
            ) As Percentile
FROM histogramTable AS ot 
) AS h
WHERE h.Percentile > @Percentile
ORDER BY Percentile;
```

Comment: I just saw your edited Question so let me some minutes to adapt my answer to fit your needs. :)

Comment: Your suggestion led to to the following which *does* work but run extremely slow: `SELECT bucket,
       (SELECT SUM(valuecount)
        FROM   mytable AS in1
        WHERE  in1.bucket <= ot.bucket) * 100 / (SELECT SUM(COUNT)
                                                 FROM   mytable AS in1)
FROM   mytable AS ot
GROUP  BY bucket
ORDER  BY bucket  `  Is there a way to do cumulative sums in SQL?

Comment: `SELECT (10+15+5+15)*.75 AS A, (10+15+5+15)*75/100 AS B`

Comment: @BogdanSahlean : Were you serious with your comment?  If so, it's a database and he can't predict the values the table will contain, neither the number of values.

Comment: @FrancisP: My comment refers to arithmetic calculations: `10/4 <> 10/4.0` (http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-4/5-0.html).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Oh that was not SQL syntax anyway, it was the calculus he wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2012, there are now SQL standard [`PERCENTILE_DISC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`PERCENTILE_CONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) inverse distribution functions, which can be used for this purpose. Unfortunately, thus far, SQL Server implements them only as window functions, not as aggregate functions.

They are not very useful on the data set that you've shown (which seems pre-aggregated), but they would definitely help on the source data set, where you could simply calculate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT percentile_disc(0.6) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bucket) OVER ()
FROM t
```

[I have blogged about percentiles in SQL here, in more detail](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/22/calculate-percentiles-to-learn-about-data-set-skew-in-sql/).